# How to merge different columns in the same file?

Tags: text-processing, csv, merge

I have three files, as shown below:

```
FILE 1: 
DATE      PGTO_CRED
20180801    50.00
20180802    150.00
20180803    130.00
20180804    110.00
20180805    200.00

FILE 2: 
DATE       PGTO_TOTAL
20180801    150.00
20180802    300.00
20180803    200.00
20180804    250.00
20180805    400.00

FILE 3: 
DATE       PGTO_FEE
20180801    35.00
20180802    10.00
20180803    25.00
20180804    140.00
20180805    135.00
```

I need my output file to be something like:

```
DATE    PGTO_CRED   PGTO_TOTAL  PGTO_FEE
20180801    50.00   150.00      35.00
20180802    150.00  300.00      10.00
20180803    130.00  200.00      25.00
20180804    110.00  250.00      140.00
20180805    200.00  400.00      135.00
```

How do I do this on Redhat Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many tools can do that, probably `awk` is the first which comes to mind, but I recommend the `join` command, especially if the input is already sorted (as in your example):

```
join file1 <(join file2 file3) | column -t
```

The `column -t` is just to nicely align the output, you can remove it.

Output:

```
DATE      PGTO_CRED  PGTO_TOTAL  PGTO_FEE
20180801  50.00      150.00      35.00
20180802  150.00     300.00      10.00
20180803  130.00     200.00      25.00
20180804  110.00     250.00      140.00
20180805  200.00     400.00      135.00
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other options:

```
paste file{1,2,3} | awk '{print $1,$2,$4,$6}' | column -t
```

or just awk:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {line[FNR] = $0; next} 
              {line[FNR] = line[FNR] OFS $2} 
    END       {for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print line[i]}
' file{1,2,3} | column -t
```